# Strange message when I run Pluto on my Windows

Tags: julia, conda, pluto

I'm running Julia 1.7.3 on Windows 11.

I'm trying to use Pluto notebooks.

I try to run Pluto using

```
julia
using Pluto
Pluto.run()
```

Pluto still runs when I do this, but I get the most bizarre message as it's firing up, basically to the effect that my system doesn't recognize conda. I'm at my wits end as to what conda has to do with Julia, and I can use anaconda on my computer (though not from the git bash terminal that I'm using to run Julia. If any one has any insight or fixes I'd be super grateful!

Here is the lightly edited error message:

```
 The term 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4
+ (& "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" " ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\user...ripts\conda.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is the info about my OS:

Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎11/‎24/‎2021
OS build    22000.795
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.795.0

Comment: Pluto does not use Conda. Have you installed Julia from Conda? Or are you using a notebook which has a Python dependency (and thus using Conda.jl)? Or do you have IJulia (Jupyter Notebook kernel) installed - this also uses Conda?

Comment: Are you running this under Powershell? It looks like the call to Conda is coming from your `WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` file as mentioned on the 4th line of the error, you might want to take a look at it to see if you (or some program) added some Conda-related stuff there.